# Cannot ssh to newly-launched instance in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

Several months ago, my friend decided to stop one of his instances. Before stopping it, he created an image of its used to launch it again in the future.

Today, I launch the new instance again from that image, but I cannot ssh into that new instance while I can still ssh into the his old instance. I use the same key pair and security group as the old instance.

The error is: ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused

What are the possible causes and how can I fix them?

Comment: Please edit your question to add output from `ssh -vvv` and a screenshot of the security group. Also give the first half of the actual IP so we can sanity-check it.

Comment: @tedder42
1 . This is the output of ssh -vvv: http://pastebin.com/Lk48QTrT
2.  This is the screenshot of the security group: http://imgur.com/PzFR7FI
3.  First half of actually IP: 54.200

Please take a look at those infomation. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Connection refused indicates a network failure when trying to ssh. You shuold make sure your server contains a security group allowing your IP to connect to the server via port 22.

Comment: I did check the security group setting. I use the same security group for both old and new instances. The old one works but the other doesn't

Comment: In that case, use ssh -vvv to provide more information about the operation and paste it along with your question.

Comment: This is the output of ssh -vvv: pastebin.com/Lk48QTrT 2. This is the screenshot of the security group: imgur.com/PzFR7FI 3. First half of actually IP: 54.200 Please take a look at those infomation. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue by adjusting the permissions of "/var/empty/sshd":

chown root:root /var/empty/sshd 
chmod 711 /var/empty/sshd

**If it does not solve your issue please share the output of telnet.**